# Drupal Error Message "Undefined array key "target_type" EntityReferenceItem.php:778"

Tags: drupal, entityreference

After upgrading to Drupal 10.2.2 (from 10.1.5), each time I try to update database or rebuild cache, I get a WARNING message related to the EntityReferenceItem class

Commands:

```
drush updatedb
```

OR

```
drush cr
```

Message:

```
 [warning] Undefined array key "target_type" EntityReferenceItem.php:778
 [warning] Undefined array key "handler_settings" EntityReferenceItem.php:779
 [warning] Undefined array key "target_type" EntityReferenceItem.php:778
 [warning] Undefined array key "handler_settings" EntityReferenceItem.php:779
 [warning] Undefined array key "target_type" EntityReferenceItem.php:778
 [warning] Undefined array key "handler_settings" EntityReferenceItem.php:779
 [warning] Undefined array key "target_type" EntityReferenceItem.php:778
 [warning] Undefined array key "handler_settings" EntityReferenceItem.php:779
 [warning] Undefined array key "target_type" EntityReferenceItem.php:778
 [warning] Undefined array key "handler_settings" EntityReferenceItem.php:779
 [warning] Undefined array key "target_type" EntityReferenceItem.php:778
 [warning] Undefined array key "handler_settings" EntityReferenceItem.php:779
 [warning] Undefined array key "target_type" EntityReferenceItem.php:778
 [warning] Undefined array key "handler_settings" EntityReferenceItem.php:779
 [warning] Undefined array key "target_type" EntityReferenceItem.php:778
 [warning] Undefined array key "handler_settings" EntityReferenceItem.php:779
 [warning] Undefined array key "target_type" EntityReferenceItem.php:778
 [warning] Undefined array key "handler_settings" EntityReferenceItem.php:779
 [warning] Undefined array key "target_type" EntityReferenceItem.php:778
 [warning] Undefined array key "handler_settings" EntityReferenceItem.php:779
```

Have you seen this error before? Any clues of how to solve it?

Thanks,

Did some research online.
Looked for patches to core ("Entity Reference") and "Dynamic Entity Reference" contributed module.

Comment: for reference, resolved here in the drupal issue queue: https://www.drupal.org/project/dynamic_entity_reference/issues/3384721 --more specific description including OP's warning message is in the following issue, which points to the above: https://www.drupal.org/project/dynamic_entity_reference/issues/3414702

Answer (score 0):

I think I did fix it going up to version 4 of Dynamic Entity Reference and after do drush updb:

```
composer require 'drupal/dynamic_entity_reference:4.x-dev@dev'
    
drush updb
```

Comment: Thank you Javier, I thought the 3x and 4x were two paths. I've been using 3.x because I was told was the path I should follow. In the past I tried to upgrade to 4x and it gave me issues...

Comment: Just tried in my local environment... updated DER to 4.0.0-alpha3 (latest) and when upgraded to Drupal 10.2.2 got the same error. Basically those warning messages show every time I runn drush updb, drush cex,drush cr... On the other hand, the site itself works (have not seen anything wrong so far).